# Redis - How to list all keys in database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I start playing with Redis, put some values into database.

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

// if you'd like to select database 3, instead of 0 (default), call
// client.select(3, function() { /* ... */ });

client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

client.set("string key", "string val", redis.print);
client.hset("hash key", "hashtest 1", "some value", redis.print);
client.hset(["hash key", "hashtest 2", "some other value"], redis.print);
client.hkeys("hash key", function (err, replies) {
    console.log(replies.length + " replies:");
    replies.forEach(function (reply, i) {
        console.log("    " + i + ": " + reply);
    });
    client.quit();
});
```

How to list all keys in database?

or is there free GUI (Redsmin https://redsmin.com/ is free only while beta)

Comment: Looks like you're looking for [`keys` command](http://redis.io/commands/keys).

Comment: Hello Paul, founder of Redsmin there, just to confirm that **there will always be a free plan in Redsmin** because we want to give back to the awesome Redis community :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **keys** method with pattern *****

According to the [docs](http://redis.io/commands/keys)

```
redis> MSET one 1 two 2 three 3 four 4
OK
redis> KEYS **
1) "one"
2) "two"
3) "three"
3) "four"
```

Answer (score 2):

This works, but as written in the docs 

*Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. **Don't use KEYS in your regular application code.** If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using SCAN or sets.*

Therefore until you work on a local project KEY command is fine, but avoid using it on production.

If you want a **Redis GUI**, you can have a look at [Redis Desktop](http://redisdesktop.com/). I work with it and it is very useful.